# Can't login into shell - password field immediately registers newline

Tags: command-line, login, password

So I need to use the command line interface without in order to install some drivers which require me to turn off the X-server.

However, I am getting the weirdest glitch, when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or open any other terminal session), I see the standard login prompt, I enter my username and hit <kbd>`Enter`</kbd>, the password prompt appears but just an instant after that, the cursor jumps to the next line, as if the system registered a newline character. After a second or so, I get `login incorrect` message with new `login` prompt and after another second I get the same message again and it loops (as if it was registering the newline again and again). Even if I start typing after the password and newline, the characters appear on screen - thus they are not getting registered as the password.

It seems like a single Enter hit fills up the buffer with several newline characters but if that were the case, I would see the cursor jump several lines immediately, which is not the case. So it seems like the newline pops into the buffer just as the prompt for the password or for the subsequent logins appear.

I thought it might be my keyboard but switching it out didn't help. Reboot didn't help either.

Do you have any idea what is going on?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1812679

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having the same problem - this is a known bug in the current kernel (as steeldriver linked https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1812679)

Solution: when booting up, go to `Advanced options` and select the previous last kernel version.